# Middle ware/Plugins for AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

Good day, everyone! I start to develop a project with aws stack. And it has one important component - [AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/appsync/) that working with a client and data. Also I have custom user structure and logic.
Now I need to add a handling for every user request (I want to check extra http header with their token). 
Can I add middle ware or plugins for AppSync with my common logic for mutation every request (for adding field with status of checking this token)?

Some solutions that go to my mind: I can add same code for every resolver. Also I can setting up identity provider with Cognito or other services but it adds more extra complexity in the project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive  research I didn't find any solutions for it. If You need the custom logic for global resolving of user requests, your own graphql server is one of the best options.